# Android drawable-hdpi-night folder

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

Please help, I am playing with small example of day-night mode in Android. So far so good. I have 2 images (of multiple size) that I am displaying depending on the phone mode (day/night), unfortunately I can't get it how, to name the folders that contain the images (in different resolution) in order to have a separate distinction. For the proper moment, the picture below contains the last try: [image: Tree structure]

and the error:

[image: Error]

Also I would like to have this structure into separate landscape/portrait folders us well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

It should be `/res/drawable-night-**`

Comment: Yes, it worked.Thanks a lot. Please forget the last part of my request. It doesn't have anything to do with the first question.

Comment: I have drawable folders: /res/drawable-port-hdpi. When I create an alternative as /res/drawable-night-port-hdpi.   It does not compile. :(