# Is there any specific resource folder in android for dark mode drawables only?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-dark-theme, android-darkmode

When I turn on dark mode in my app, the icon of some dialogs is not visible because they are dark. I created those drawables with the "New Image Asset" option in the Android studio.  is there any specific resource folder for dark mode drawables?

Comment: You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41937678/android-drawable-hdpi-night-folder

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the folders like:

```
res\drawable-night\
.....
res\drawable-night-xxhdpi
res\drawable-night-xxxhdpi
```

In general if you need to use the `night` qualifier ,appending multiple qualifiers, you must place them in the **same order** in which they are listed in table [reported in the doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources). If the qualifiers are ordered wrong, the resources are ignored.